# app.use and app.get (or app.post) node.js express

Tags: node.js, express

I'd like to use a app.use:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log('%s %s', req.method, req.url);
    next();
});
```

But it only works if I have no app.get or app.post in my code, if I have one my app.use is ignore.

I'd like to execute a script each time a app.get or a app.use is called

I also try:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log('%s %s', req.method, req.url);
    app.get('/',function(req,res){console.log('aa')})
    next();
});
```

in this case my app.get is ignore

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to put your `app.use()` above the router. The router is usually inside the express configuration so just put your `app.use()` above the configuration. Something like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('awesome');
  next();
})

app.configure(function(){
  // config
  app.use(app.router);
});
```

Also have a look at the build in [logger](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/logger.html).