# What unique functionality does app.post( .. ) provide, in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

`app.post` is not documented in expressjs.com. As I understand, the server listens to a url requestion `/` etc. which then invokes a middleware and a callback. But all this is same in `app.get`.

What unique value does it provide to express?

PS. There are other questions like [Express Framework app.post and app.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087696/express-framework-app-post-and-app-get), or [app.use and app.get (or app.post) node.js express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450228/app-use-and-app-get-or-app-post-node-js-express) but reading answers to the same does not provide the answer to teh question.

Edit:

The following code provides for invocation of both `app.get` and `app.post` on `/login` request from the browswer. Are both `app.get` and `app.post` invoked? (Presumably in the order of appearance. )

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res){
var username = req.user ? req.user.username : ''; res.render('login', { title: 'authenticate', username: username,
});
message: req.flash('error') });
app.post('/login',
passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: true }), function(req, res) {
res.redirect('/admin'); });

enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd not say it's [not documented](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB), but basically it does the same as `app.get()` does for `HTTP GET`, but instead only matches `HTTP POST` requests.

If you don't know what the difference between a `POST` and a `GET` is, you can for example take a look [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html).

As for your sample code, either your get or your post handler is invoked, depending on whether the browser does a post or a get request. Both are never invoked for the same request.

Comment: The 'here' link you provide refers to html 2.0 standards. Are they still applicable? (in html 5, world) It seems to be a pretty informative link.